# Issue with retrieving AJAX result

Tags: java, jquery, playframework

I'm attempting to retrieve an AJAX result from an action using Play!

I've got the following route configured:

```
GET     /User/checkEmail                        User.checkEmail
```

Within User I've for this for my action:

```
public static void checkEmail(String email)
{
    renderJSON(email);
}
```

Just so that I can send back the email that was passed in (for debugging purposes). I'm triggering the ajax call like so:

```
$.get("/User/checkEmail", {'email': sEmail.value}, function(json) {
    console.info("yo");
});
```

I can see that the action gets called and receives the email address. I can see the GET result in the net tab of firebug (with the retured email). The callback function doesn't seem to get called. I've also tried calling renderJSON('{"email": 'email'}'), but that doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you change `console.info("yo");` to `alert(1);` does it pop up the alert?  Also, just a side note, you will need to tell the `.get` method to use 'json' as the type.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, jQuery doesn't like JSON returned with single quotes, so double quotes solved this issue. I'll should probably pass in an object to renderJSON to avoid this issue.

Answer (score -2):

Sure it isnt `console.info` and you mean `console.log`?

Else try doing the following and see if it yields any results:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/User/checkEmail',
    data: {
        'email': sEmail.value
    },
    success: function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: try console.info in your console. It works fine as well.
$.get is also shorthand for $.ajax and also should work just fine.